# TFS Build Report: Where Do come "Other Errors and Warnings" from?

Tags: tfsbuild

I get random NullReferenceExceptions which do show up on top of the Build Report before any other content and under the "Other Errors and Warnings". My question is how can I find the root cause of this since setting the build to diagnostic level does not lead to any clues. Could it be a parallel activity that has thrown an exception in another thread or could it be an internal error inside the build agent?

Comment: Does your build fail? What does the log with set diagnostic show? Within which activity do these errors occur? Do they occur in each and every build?

Comment: It is a sporadic exception and the build is partially succeeded. It could be that during testing something bad happens. But I do not know under what circumstances an exception is displayed on top of the build report.

Comment: The sequence in the Summary View is a matter of Priority, see this post for an explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/08/09/tfs2010-customizing-the-build-details-view-summary-view.aspx. It can be assumed that TFS auto-assigns these priotities based on internal rules

Comment: Each Build, once opened, presents with a Summary View (that's where you are when viewing "other errors & warnings"). There is also a "View Log" that lists a detailed sequence of actions. Normally, with verbosity=diagnostic, you should here at least get some hints on what's going on. Is this not the case?

Comment: Nope Diagnostics does not help. It seems that the exception orignates somewhere in between the workflow engine and the build controler. But I cannot be sure since I do not know under which circumstances exceptions are printed before any of our build log is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. After putting try/catch around the complete build workflow and another one around the build agent scope I did find that during the gated checkin activity outside the agent scope a NullReferenceException did occur.

The interesting thing was that it did happen inside an Assign activity originating from some VB lambda expression. It turned out the activity got some argument of the form

> Assign To="[Var]" From="[SomeObject.Property]"

*SomObject* was null so the property evaluation inside the lambda did hickup with an NullReferenceException.